# Logging configuration for Mule

Tags: logging, mule

I am using log4j to control mule logging. I am trying to find the best way to do the following:

I want to set category for all loggers so that I can output them to a single file.

- Logging from Scripts: I can see there is a 'log' in the context of groovy scripts but how do I set a category on it?
- Logging from subflow: The subflow is being from many flows. Each flow has their own category and logs to different file. How do I pass the logging category to the Loggers in the subflow so that they log with the appropiate category?
- I tried to set the category in the INVOCATION SCOPE of mule and tried to access it with #[header:INVOCATION:LOGGER_Category] inside the Category of the Logger component. But looks like it doesn't evaluate that Category component (I was expecting the same behavior of 'Message').

Any clue will be very much appreciated.

-Sajid.

Answer (score 0):

- In a flow use: `<logger category="yourCategory" ... />`
- In a Groovy Script, do not use the provided `log` variable but create your own from the log factory.
- In a MEL Script, create your logger from the factory too.